# Telegram Bot not Connecting to API

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have been using the Telegram API for a while to listen for messages in specific channels on one account. The code below works ok. I tried to use the same code to create another listener for a different account but it doesn't work. I don't get any errors.

When I look on the official Telegram app the listener is not listed under "Devices" which suggests it is not connecting to the API correctly.

Before testing I created a new API ID and hash at my.telegram.org. I've triple checked that the ID, hash and channel ID are all correct.

Can anyone think what the issue might be?

Thanks

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

api_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
chat_id = xxxxxxxx

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_id))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    new_message = event.message.message
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print(chat_id)
    print(new_message)
    print()

    screenshot = "new_image.jpg"

    if event.message.photo:
        await event.download_media(screenshot)
        print("New image received")
```

Comment: Please provide more of your code, we can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

`@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[chat_id]))`

chats=[] - here must be a python list,
like chats=[-123456789]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).